# Postgres JSON array with join?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a few tables with a foreign key relationship.

**books**

| Column | Type |
| --- | --- |
| id | int4 |
| title | varchar(200) |
| ... | ... |

**book_authors**

| Column | Type |
| --- | --- |
| id | int4 |
| name | varchar(50) |
| url | varchar(200) |

**book_authors_lookup**

| Column | Type |
| --- | --- |
| book_id | int4 |
| author_id | int4 |

**book_tags**

| Column | Type |
| --- | --- |
| id | int4 |
| book_id | int4 |
| name | varchar(50) |

I want JSON output something like this:

```json
{
  "books": [
    {
      "book_id": 1,
      "title": "Book 1 Title",
      "authors": [
        {"name": "John Doe", "url": "http://twitter/@johndoe"},
        {"name": "Jane Doe", "url": "http://twitter/@janedoe"}
      ],
      "tags": ["tag1", "tag2"]
    },
    {
      // Next book
    }
  ]
}
```

I don't necessarily need that `books` root-level object if it's too difficult to include.  I can probably just deal with the array itself.

I have no clue how to do this.  I've started out with something like this:

```sql
select json_build_object(
  'book_id', b.id,
  'title', b.title,
  'authors', json_build_array(??)
  'tags', json_build_array(??)
)
from books b
join book_tags bt on bt.book_id = b.id
join book_authors_lookup bal on bal.book_id = b.id
join book_authors ba on ba.id = bal.author_id
```

Comment: I think you need subselects for `authors` and `tags`. Can you prepare a [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com) with example of data? You will get an answer much faster if you do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest "knitting" the JSON structure like this.

```sql
with t as
(
 select 
    b.id as book_id, 
    b.title, 
    (
        select jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('name', ba.name, 'url', ba.url)) 
        from book_authors ba 
        inner join book_authors_lookup bal on ba.id = bal.author_id 
        where bal.book_id = b.id
    ) as authors,
    (
        select array_agg(bt.name)
        from book_tags bt
        where bt.book_id = b.id
    ) as tags
 from books b    
)
select jsonb_build_object('books', jsonb_agg(to_json(t.*))) from t;
```

Pls. note that the above script has not been tested so there might be trivial errors.

Comment: Wow, thanks! Only thing I had to change was to remove the quotes for : `ba.'url'` to `ba.url`. Worked perfectly!

Comment: Copy/paste :). Fixed it too.